# IS NOT NULL returns all rows including column with NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which has multiple columns, but I am ONLY INTERESTED to get two columns col-A & col-B, with the condition that the row will have:
col-A be any value & col-B must be NOT NULL.

I well searched this forum and in the most simplest tried, the one given below:

```
SELECT col-A,col-B FROM ports WHERE col-B IS NOT NULL;
```

when I run this query it dumps  both columns comprising rows which have:  (please note-- here "ports" is the table)

```
col-A = ANY VALUE + col-B = NULL(blank/empty field)
col-A = ANY VALUE + col-B = NON NULL
```

Even I tried. the most generic syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM ports WHERE col-B IS NOT NULL; <<<< it dumps both empty & non-empty rows
```

MySQL version is 5.5.32.

Answer (score 2):

Check for both conditions: Blank and `null`

```
SELECT col-A,col-B 
FROM ports 
WHERE col-B IS NOT NULL and col-B <> ''
```

blank is not `null`. `null` means no value and a blank empty string is `''`

Comment: @plainjane: Accepting is totally up to the OP. Please don't call someone to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @uergen d works fine. But if you want try an other method check this

```
SELECT col-A,col-B 
FROM ports 
WHERE LENGTH(col-B) > 0
```